# Stone-Weierstrass: Examples

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

By Stone-Weierstrass one has: $f\in\mathcal{C}(K):\quad p_n\to f$

Now, for analytic functions this is just Taylor:
$$f\in\mathcal{C}^\omega([a,b]):\quad f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$$

But, how does this work for other examples like:
$$K:=[-1,1]:\quad f(x):=|x|$$
$$L:=[-1,-\frac12]\cup[\frac12,1]:\quad g(x):=\frac{1}{x}$$
*(Note that the latter is over a disconnected space.)*

Comment: You can construct explicit examples using the Berstein polynomials, say. Your question seems a little fuzzy. "How [does] this work...?"? What do you mean?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Like I was just curious about what the sequence looks like for these examples.

Comment: You can use software to plot them, I suppose.

Comment: Ah and the Bernstein polynomials offer a way for uniform approximation.

Comment: A function real-analytic on $[a,b]$ need not be the sum of a power series on the whole interval at once.

Comment: @GEdgar: Oh you're right I forgot: $f(x):=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\quad(x\in[-2,2])$

Comment: A quick googling gave [this](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/barbeau/hxpol5.pdf) that might be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As mentioned by Pedro Tamaroff Bernstein Polynomials do the job.*

Consider for example:
$$f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}:f(x):=|x|$$

Then the first six polynomials are:
$$B_1(x)=1$$
$$B_2(x)=\frac12(1+x^2)$$
$$B_3(x)=\frac12(1+x^2)$$
$$B_4(x)=\frac{1}{8}(3+6x^2-x^4)$$
$$B_5(x)=\frac{1}{8}(3+6x^2-x^4)$$
$$B_6(x)=\frac{1}{16}(5+15x^2-5x^4+x^6)$$

Answer (score 4):

> how does this work for other examples

**Not** via a Taylor series, that's for sure. The difference between

1. $f$ is the limit of a uniformly converging power series,

and

2. $f$ is the limit of a uniformly converging sequence of polynomials

is that partial sums of a power series are a very special kind of a sequence of polynomials: for every $k$, the coefficient of $x^k$ is the same in all polynomials of degree at least $k$.

A nondifferentiable continuous function like $|x|$ can be approximated in the second sense but not the first.

Comment: That for sure, I was just curious how such an approximation looks like...

Comment: Bernstein polynomials are completely explicit; You can take any $f$ you want and just plot them. I experimented with them and Taylor polynomials [here](http://calculus7.org/2014/09/07/squarish-polynomials/), although not for the purpose of uniform approximation.

Answer (score 3):

Let us recall the Lebesgue's proof of Weierstrass approximation theorem.

**Step1.** If we are able to provide a polynomial approximation for $|x|$ over $[-1,1]$ with an arbitrarily small uniform error, we can do the same for any continuous function over a closed interval.

*Proof*: Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function over $I=[0,1]$. Since $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous over $I$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the difference between $f(x)$ and the spline through the points $(0,f(0)),\left(\frac{1}{n},f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right),\ldots,\left(\frac{n-1}{n},f\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\right),(1,f(1))$ is bounded by $\varepsilon$ in absolute value. Since any spline is just a linear combination with bounded coefficients of functions like $|x-\alpha|$ for some $\alpha\in I$, a uniform polynomial approximation for $|x|$ grants the existence of a uniform polynomial approximation for any continuous function.

**Step2.** To provide a uniform polynomial approximation for $|x|$, we may consider the truncated Taylor series for $\sqrt{1-y}$ in a neighbourhood of $y=0$, then evaluate it in $y=1-x^2$. As an alternative, a uniform approximation is given by a Fourier series:
$$ P_{2n}(x)\triangleq\frac{2}{\pi}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{4(-1)^j}{(4j^2-1)\pi}\,T_{2j}(x),$$
where $T_{2j}$ is a Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind and:
$$ \|P_{2n}(x)-|x|\|_{\infty} = P_{2n}(0) = \frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}.$$

---

About the function defined over a disconnected domain $D$: it is sufficient to take a continuous function $g(x)$ over $E=\operatorname{Conv}(D)$ such that $g_{|D}\equiv f$, then approximate $g(x)$ over $E$.